# Return to binary private key secp256k1 from hex DER

Tags: openssl, private-key, encryption-asymmetric, der

I want to get `private_key.pem` from `foo_priv.key`

```
$ openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -out private_key.pem   
$ openssl ec -in private_key.pem -outform DER|tail -c +8|head -c 32 |xxd -p -c 32 > foo_priv.key
```

I tried with

```
$ openssl ec -noout -text -inform DER -in foo_priv.key
read EC key
unable to load Key

$ openssl x509 -in foo_priv.key -inform DER -outform PEM
unable to load certificate
4486393452:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1220:
4486393452:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:386:Type=X509

$ cat foo_priv.key | xxd -r -p  > test.bin  
$ openssl ec -in test.bin -inform DER -pubin -text -noout                
read EC key
unable to load Key
4456304236:error:0D06B08E:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO:not enough data:a_d2i_fp.c:247:
```

Comment: `openssl x509` processes only certificates and sometimes CSRs, never any kind of key, much less a key in a format that OpenSSL doesn't support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tail` and `head` mechanisms to extract the private part of your key gives you just its bytes. However, OpenSSL needs more than that to store the private key information. If you are using OpenSSL 1.1.1, you can extract the required bytes using the `-no_public` option of the `ec` tool, like this:

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key.pem -outform DER -no_public | xxd -p -c 32
read EC key
writing EC key
302e020101042031792710388085aaec53a04072a231116dc102e63cccdf5e85
ddd875cab6be6da00706052b8104000a
```

Comparing this to you original approach, you can see that information was lost there:

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key.pem -outform DER | tail -c +8 | head -c 32 | xxd -p -c 32
read EC key
writing EC key
31792710388085aaec53a04072a231116dc102e63cccdf5e85ddd875cab6be6d
```

In general, these files are stored in ASN.1 format which you can not easily modify without breaking it. To get a feel for the additional information that you removed, you could use

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key.pem -no_public | openssl asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  46 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:31792710388085AAEC53A04072A231116DC102E63CCCDF5E85DDD875CAB6BE6D
   39:d=1  hl=2 l=   7 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
   41:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :secp256k1
```

Note the 32 bytes in the `OCTET STRING` section, which are exactly the ones you were extracting. But there is additional information about the curve type as well as a version number of the key format. This follows the private EC key format as outlined in [RFC 5915: Elliptic Curve Private Key Structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915), section 3. Without that information, OpenSSL can not reconstruct the private key.

---

If you still want to reconstruct your private key file from the 32 key bytes after reading all this, you could achieve this with the (brittle) mechanism of prepending `302e0201010420` and appending `a00706052b8104000a` and converting the result to its binary form. Something like

```
$ cat <(echo 302e0201010420) foo_priv.key <(echo a00706052b8104000a) | xxd -r -p | openssl ec -inform DER
read EC key
writing EC key
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQEEIDF5JxA4gIWq7FOgQHKiMRFtwQLmPMzfXoXd2HXKtr5toAcGBSuBBAAK
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks for update I'm doing before your new update :) `cat <(echo 302e0201010420) foo_priv.key <(echo a00706052b8104000a) | xxd -r -p | openssl ec -inform DER -noout -text` Now I need to convert to get `-----BEGIN EC PARAMETERS-----
BgUrgQQACg==
-----END EC PARAMETERS-----
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEINshlkHT/vOa2QUHTaBWr7T7aP8DfWML/XjvpxQLtS8coAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAE4uaCjMgUknV+k/qmsYWQN0085v+1mrk/n7X6ZD2rsWk/F0LYR1vohCPZ
/ByWE+p7N/w9hzLIVfclaxnnqBC/lA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: So did that suggestion work for you? If you have a new question, please post it as a new question.

Comment: M goal is get `private_key.pem`where `private_key.pem` is `BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY`...

Comment: Updated my answer to give you PEM format at the end. And add `-out private_key.pem` at the end if you want it to go to a file as opposed to `stdout`.

Comment: thanks again! why the result is different?  the output is different form `cat private_key.pem` https://pastebin.com/JCy43u0X

Comment: you original `private_key.pem` includes the private as well as the public key. If you use `openssl ec -noout -text -in private_key.pem`, the outputs should be the same.

Comment: `openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256k1 -rand /dev/urandom -noout -text -out private_key.pem` I tried with that command but the output is different

Comment: I don't understand your question. This command generates a new key (`-genkey`) so the output is definitely going to be different from your previous key.

Comment: yes sorry, I mean, i'd like to get the same output of `private_key.pem`. (https://pastebin.com/JCy43u0X)

Comment: That will not be possible with just the OpenSSL tools. You will need to do some OpenSSL programming. Probably better to ask a new question.